# HTML newsletter - remove iphone underline

Tags: html, iphone, ipad, newsletter

I am developing a newsletter which should work on Outlook 2007 iPhone and iPad.
Ideally I would like to have links in the footer which are underlined but iPad and iPhone add their blue underline automatically to any link. And I can't get rid of it in any way (I googled already and read at least 10 different articles about this problematic)

Can someone please help me understanding what I do wrong?
I tried with lists but I can't get them on the same line anymore.
This is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style _tmplitem="50" >
.article-content ol, .article-content ul {
margin: 0 0 0 24px;
padding: 0;
list-style-position: inside;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (max-width: 610px) {
a[class=no-underline]{text-decoration:none;color:#00FF00}
}

.l-footer a {
color: #b2b2b2 !important; text-decoration: underline;
}
.l-footer a:link {
color: #b2b2b2 !important; text-decoration:  underline;
}
.l-footer a:visited {
color: #b2b2b2; text-decoration: underline;
}
.l-footer a:hover {
color: #b2b2b2; text-decoration: underline;
}
.l-footer a:active {
color: #b2b2b2;text-decoration: underline;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="background-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
<table class="w600 l-content-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td class="w600" height="55" width="600" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
<table class="l-footer" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td width="400" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
<table class="small-font" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; font-size: 12px; color: #b2b2b2 !important; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td class="no-underline" class='is-last' style="letter-spacing: 0; padding-right: 12px; ">
<font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
<a href="http://www.lyra.net/fabio" target="blank" style="line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;color: #b2b2b2;">
Responsibles
</a>
</font>
</td>
<td class="no-underline" class='is-last' style="letter-spacing: 0; padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px; border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2;">
<font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
<a href="http://www.lyra.net/fabio" target="blank" style="line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;color: #b2b2b2;">
Disclaimer
</a>
</font>
</td>
<td class="no-underline" class='is-last' style="letter-spacing: 0; padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px; border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2;">
<font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
<a href="http://www.lyra.net/fabio" target="blank" style="line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;color: #b2b2b2;">
Feedback
</a>
</font>
</td>
<td class="no-underline" class='is-last' style="letter-spacing: 0; padding-right: 12px; padding-left: 12px; border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2;">
<font style=' color: #b2b2b2;'>
<a href="http://www.lyra.net/fabio" target="blank" style="line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;color: #b2b2b2;">
RSS feeds
</a>
</font>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td width="210" align="right" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
<table class="small-font" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; font-size: 12px; color: #b2b2b2 !important; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
<tr>
<td class="is-first" style="color: #6f6f6f;letter-spacing: 0; padding: 0px; border: 0px">
<span style="color: #b2b2b2; line-height: inherit; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
&copy; 2013&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- block footer ends -->
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

To test my code I send the HTML page as email from IE8

Comment: I realise you said you had done some research on google however I had the same issue developing a mobile website for iOS and this helped me out a great deal http://litmus.com/blog/remove-blue-links-ios

Comment: Hello Alec! I read that article already and I think it deals only with automatically generated links (it uses "span a" on text that will be transformed as a link). Besides, what I would really like to achieve is that the underline is correctly colored also on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the only solution I found is including the links in a single-element unordered list. This will ensure that the right underline color is applied also on iPhone.

```
<td style="letter-spacing: 0;  border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2;" width="120">
    <ul style='list-style:none;' class="list">
        <li class="plus last" style='margin-left:8px; border-top:0px;border-bottom:0px;'>
            <font style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 11px;color: #ffffff;">
                <a href="http://www.test.com" target='blank'>Rss Feeds</a>
            </font>
        </li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

and this is the style

```
.list {
list-style:none;
margin:0px 0 0px 0px;
padding:0;
}
li.plus {
display:block;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-decoration:none;
font-size: 12px;
}
li.plus a{
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right: 8px;
}
li.last a{
    padding-right: 0px;
}
li.first a{
    padding-left: 0px;
}
a:link {
color:#b2b2b2;;
text-decoration:underline;
}
a:visited {
color:#b2b2b2;;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
color:#b2b2b2;;
text-decoration:underline;
}
a:active {
color:#b2b2b2;;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your head section of the page

```
<style type=”text/css”>

.appleLinks a {color:#000000; text-decoration: none;}

.appleLinksWhite a {color:#ffffff; text-decoration: none;}

</style>
```

and it will stop links appearing blue in iOS and instead make them white. Just change the colour to what you require.

Answer (score 0):

You can also throw plain `<span>` tags in between all text that would be turned into an unstyled link in outlook / gmail / ios, for example-

```
call 1 - 55<span>5 - 314 - 5</span>678
25 L Str<span>eet, Bosto</span>n MA 11385
```