# Getting rid of bullet list decoration in iphone Apple Mail

Tags: html, iphone, newsletter

I am still fighting with newsletter implementation on iPhone (tested with Apple Mail)
The following code works perfectly in Outlook2007. On the iPhone, unfortunately, the bullet list decorations are shown (even though it is stated that they should not be displayed). (I wish I could post a screenshot but I don't have enough reputation yet :))

How can i get rid of the bullets?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style type="text/css">
.list {
list-style: none;
margin:0px 0 0px 0px;
padding:0;
-webkit-text-size-adjust:
}
li.plus {
display:block;
list-style: none;
list-style-type: none;
margin:0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
text-decoration:none;
font-size: 12px;
}
a:link {
color:#b2b2b2;;
text-decoration:underline;
}
a:visited {
color:#b2b2b2;;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
color:#b2b2b2;;
text-decoration:underline;
}
a:active {
color:#b2b2b2;;
text-decoration:none;
}

</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table class="w600 l-content-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
            <tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="w600" height="55" width="600" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
                        <table class="l-footer" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
                            <tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="480" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
                                        <table class="small-font" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; font-size: 12px; color: #b2b2b2 !important; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
                                            <tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="letter-spacing: 0;" width="120">
                                                        <ul style='list-style:none;' class="list">
                                                            <li class="plus first" >
                                                                <font style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 11px;color: #ffffff;">
                                                                    <a href="http://www.test.com" target='blank'>Responsibles</a>
                                                                </font>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="letter-spacing: 0; border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2;" width="110">
                                                        <ul style='list-style:none;' class="list">
                                                            <li class="plus" style='margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;'>
                                                                <font style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 11px;color: #ffffff;">
                                                                    <a href="http://www.test.com" target='blank'>Disclaimer</a>
                                                                </font>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="letter-spacing: 0; border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2;" width="110">
                                                        <ul style='list-style:none;' class="list">
                                                            <li class="plus" style='margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px; border-top:0px;border-bottom:0px;'>
                                                                <font style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 11px;color: #ffffff;">
                                                                    <a href="http://www.test.com" target='blank'>Feedback</a>
                                                                </font>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="letter-spacing: 0;  border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2;" width="120">
                                                        <ul style='list-style:none;' class="list">
                                                            <li class="plus last" style='margin-left:8px; margin-right: 0px;border-top:0px;border-bottom:0px;'>
                                                                <font style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 11px;color: #ffffff;">
                                                                    <a href="http://www.test.com" target='blank'>Rss Feeds</a>
                                                                </font>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="140" align="right" style="color: #6f6f6f; border: #6f6f6f;">
                                        <table class="small-font" style="letter-spacing: -0.01em; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: arial; text-align: left; font-size: 12px; color: #b2b2b2 !important; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
                                            <tbody style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="color: #6f6f6f;letter-spacing: 0; padding: 0px; border: 0px">
                                                        <span style="color: #b2b2b2; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;">
                                                            &copy; 2013&nbsp;&nbsp;LLLLVSKI
                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably get rid of all those inline styles, it makes it kind of hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: You need `inline` styles if you're doing HTML Emails.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use lists in your example - there is no point. Also, margin isn't supported in Outlook 2013, so you should avoid that in email.

It looks like you are using the margin and lists to inset (left pad) your hyperlinked text.

Use one to the following two methods instead:

```
<!-- padding applied to the table cell -->
<table width="120" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="letter-spacing: 0;  border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2; padding-left:20px;" width="120">
      Text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br><br>

<!-- empty cell as padding -->
<table width="120" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-left: 1px solid #b2b2b2;" width="20">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td style="letter-spacing: 0;" width="100">
      Text
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Padding can sometimes collapse when someone forwards an email, if that is something you are concerned about, the most rock solid method is option 2.

Comment: Hello! I have to use list because so far it's the only way I found to avoid the blue underline that appears on iOS (see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090744/html-newsletter-remove-iphone-underline?rq=1 ). Also, I am developing only for Outlook2007 and iOS.

Comment: `<a href="" style="color: #000001; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">text</a>` works fine for me.